menu does not appear on mobile, safari browser
So I have this problem, on Chrome (mobile view) when I click burger menu button (btn) (SVG icon), it shows me menu and other page links (as it should). But on Safari it just does not show.
HTML:
    <div class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon">
        <img src="./Icons/menuIcon.svg" alt="burger menu icon">
    </div>
    <div class="closeIcon" id="closeIcon">
        <img src="./Icons/closeIcon.svg" alt="close icon">
    </div>


JS:
    const menuIcon = document.getElementById("menuIcon");
    const closeIcon = document.getElementById("closeIcon");
    const mobileLinks = document.getElementById("mobileLinks");

    menuIcon.addEventListener("click", function(){
        menuIcon.style.display = "none";
        closeIcon.style.display = "block";
        mobileLinks.style.display = "block"
    })

    closeIcon.addEventListener("click", function(){
        menuIcon.style.display = "block";
        closeIcon.style.display = "none";
        mobileLinks.style.display = "none"
    })

I tried clearing cache, did not worked, could not think any other way to make this happen, I want to menu show when I click on menu icon on mobile view Safari browser.
In Safari console, error is:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///favicon.ico

but I don't have favicon linked or anything, just SVG icon.

Welcome to SO! Ideally, we need a minimal reproducible example of your code shown in the Code Snippet so that we can run it and see the problem. Your code above doesn't contain anything critical that can prevent your menu from showing. I assume you have some issues with CSS styles. But to verify this assumption, we need a running minimal piece of your code. In many cases, cutting unnecessary parts to extract the key block that leads to the problem, will take you to the problem even without SO.

There are online icon converters from SVG (or PNG) to fav-icons.
